# Translate: Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n (line 1)

Tags: logstash

I am struggling with a translation dilemma, I have been researching for hrs for answers, but i havent found the right one for my issue, and i do not know why i am getting this error:

> Translate: Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n (line 1)

Problem:

I have a translation set in logstash as below:

```
translate {
field => "module_id"
destination => "module_name_eng"
dictionary_path => "........./translation/translate_module.csv"
}
```

My translation file looks like this:

```
120,XXXX
778,YYYY
```

Also enclosed:

[image]

I have no extra char after the first line.
Interestingly the very same file with one line is working, but when i add a new (so with 2 lines) I am getting the above error: *Translate: Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n (line 1)*

I really do not understand why, obviously i am doing something wrong, but what it is?
Please help, it is driving me crazy, I have tried almost everything in the file now.

Thank you.

Comment: Switch to another dictionary format, like YAML?

Comment: That is not really an option at this moment, i need to solve it for csv. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: no, sorry. I tried to reproduce your error but logstash was failing to start whenever I tried to use a csv dictionary. Perhaps ask over on the official forums (https://discuss.elastic.co/)?

Comment: thank you for the try, i addressed it there too, no reply yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now it is solved with yml file, since Excel is just not working

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes across this problem (happened to me when going from LS 6.6. to 6.8.). Converting the line ends from \r \n (0xOD 0xOA) to \n fixed the problem for me.